# How to create multi-content document in filenet p8?

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

I have a requirement of creating multi-content document in FileNet. e.g. Let's say that I need to have one document which consists of a word document, A JPEG file and a MP4 video file as its content.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content of a `Document` is stored as [ContentElement](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iconf/v5r2m0/topic/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.java.doc/com/filenet/api/core/ContentElement.html). `Document` can have multiple `Content Elements` – with their own MIME-type, name, etc.

[Documents / Document Content](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iconf/v5r2m0/topic/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/document_concepts.htm?path=11_1_1_10_1#document_concepts__doc_concepts_content)

Comment: Is it not necessary to set the MIME type of the final document with all the content elements when you checkin the document? If you can give me a sample code please?

Comment: Question not understood. Sample code can be found in FileNet Info Сenter - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iconf/v5r2m0/topic/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/document_procedures.htm?path=11_1_1_10_4_6#document_procedures__doc_procedures_set_content

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in 2 way . 1) Through Workplace/XT - while adding document you need to select Compound Document as Yes and need to followup the document add wizard to get the all docuemnts added in filenet .
2) In FEM lunch New Document wizard , on bottom check Compound Document and complete the wizard by adding all documents .

Comment: Compound Document and multi content document are 2 different concepts. In compound Document you create a document hierarchy(parent-child relationship) where in multi-content document situation you create a single document instance to have a multiple content elements. Content elements can be an instance of content transfer object or an instance of content referential object .